# Using apt/aptitude, how to remove all legacy packages that are sourceless after a distro-upgrade?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, aptitude, dist-upgrade

I upgraded my linux from Pop_OS 21.10 to 22.04 a few weeks ago.

The distro-upgrade presumably replaced some old sources with new versions, as a result, many existing packages for Pop_OS 21.10 or earlier versions are now sourceless:

```
$ sudo aptitude update
W: Package containerd.io had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 1.4.13-1 is not available
W: Package scala-cli had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 0.1.2 is not available
W: Package libfam0 had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 2.7.0-17.3build2 is not available
W: Package ksysguardd had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 4:5.22.0-0ubuntu1 is not available
W: Package gnome-getting-started-docs-de had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1 is not available
W: Package gnome-getting-started-docs-es had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1 is not available
W: Package gnome-getting-started-docs-fr had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1 is not available
W: Package gnome-getting-started-docs-it had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1 is not available
W: Package gnome-getting-started-docs-ja had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1 is not available
W: Package gnome-getting-started-docs-pt had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1 is not available
W: Package gnome-getting-started-docs-ru had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.36.2-0ubuntu0.1 is not available
W: Package docker-ce-cli had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 5:20.10.12~3-0~ubuntu-focal is not available
W: Package wolframscript had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 1.2.0+2019040701 is not available
W: Package libvala-0.48-0 had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 0.48.6-0ubuntu1 is not available
W: Package linux-headers-5.11.0-7614-generic had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 5.11.0-7614.15~1622578982~20.04~383c0a9 is not available
W: Package llvm-10-dev had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 is not available
W: Package linux-headers-5.15.8-76051508-generic had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 5.15.8-76051508.202112141040~1639505278~20.04~0ede46a is not available
W: Package ksysguard had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 4:5.22.0-0ubuntu1 is not available
W: Package gcc-8 had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 8.5.0-0ubuntu4 is not available
W: Package linux-modules-5.16.19-76051619-generic had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 5.16.19-76051619.202204081339~1649696161~22.04~091f44b is not available
W: Package minikube had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 1.25.2-0 is not available
W: Package oem-sutton.newell-meta had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 4.0newell5 is not available
W: Package linux-modules-5.15.8-76051508-generic had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 5.15.8-76051508.202112141040~1639505278~20.04~0ede46a is not available
W: Package libllvm10 had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1 is not available
W: Package gcc-8-base had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 8.5.0-0ubuntu4 is not available
W: Package libsepol1 had been marked to reinstall, but the file for the current installed version 3.1-1ubuntu2.1 is not available
```

I need to remove all of them (otherwise they waste disk space and may cause strange conflicts), how do I do this? Solution can be provided using any Ubuntu/debian based package manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily extract the package names by saving that output to a file (e.g. with redirection or just mouse copy and paste since it's a fairly small list) and running it through `awk '{print $3}'`, as the package names are in the third field of each line.  You can then use those package names with an `apt-get remove` or `apt-get purge` command.

You can also get a list of "obsolete" packages using `aptitude search` - e.g. `aptitude -F %p search '?obsolete'`.  This will probably produce a much larger list of package names than just those that are "marked to reinstall"...but it's impossible to tell for sure without knowing your sources.list configuration and the current state of any repos you're using.

However, automatically removing a large number of packages will probably end up removing far more than you thought it would, because other packages may depend upon some of the packages that you are removing.   Library packages (e.g. `libfam0`, `libvala-0.48-0`, and `libsepol1`) are especially likely to cause this. And removing `containerd.io` is likely to cause docker or similar container-management tools to be uninstalled.

I strongly advise against automating the removal of these packages.

Selectively uninstalling hand-picked packages **if and when they prove to be a problem** should be fine but (with a few exceptions) the amount of disk space they consume is not worth the risk of removing them without cause.

Old kernel headers are fairly large (~50MB) and usually safe to remove - they're really only useful if you need to compile kernel modules (e.g. with dkms) for installed kernels. And you probably don't need the gnome getting started docs in so many languages.

You may also find that you are removing a package that you use regularly but is no longer in the distro because the package maintainer no longer has time to maintain it.  I know that there are several like that on my Debian machines, especially those that have been continuously upgraded since the 1990s.  I'd hate to have my roxterm packages auto-removed, for example - it's years obsolete and abandoned even by the author, but I still use it because it sucks a lot less than any of the other libvte-based terminal emulators....and, even though it's abandonware, it still works just fine.

BTW, it's worth remembering that the `W:` prefix to each line is indicating a **warning**, not an error condition.  It's pointing out something that is worth being aware of, but isn't necessarily an actual problem that needs to be fixed.